# Sending apollo request outside batch

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have an apollo frontend with [batch requests](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http.html) set up. However there are certain requests that shouldn't be included in the batch:

- A component depends on a "small" version of a request to load
- The "full" request should happen at the same time, to be entered into the cache for later use
- If the small and full request are sent in the same batch it doesn't return until the full one is finished, which takes too long.

I've thought of two non-ideal solutions:

- Start the full request once the small one is finished, using `onCompleted`. Not ideal because for speed I'd like to start the two simultaneously
- Set up two backend endpoints, one with batching and one without, and use [split](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/composition.html) to direct requests where appropriate. Would work but I'd like to get away without an extra endpoint

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've realised that the first solution is no good because it can cause other unrelated queries to be delayed - so the only option so far is the last solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert on the topic but it seems that `batchKey` option in [apllo-link-batch-http](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-batch-http#options) is what you are looking for. The easiest would be to for example prefix your operations with a keyword:

```
const link = BatchHttpLink({
  batchKey: operation =>
    operation.name && operation.name.value.startsWith('eager_') ? 'eager' : 'normal'
});
```